# How to call a nested function in a class in python

Tags: python, class, oop

i have a class called animals. inside of the animals class there is a function called printAnimalsNames and inside of printAnimalsNames there is another function called printAnimalsOwner
how to call the printAnimalsOwner from printAnimalsNames?

for example:

```
class animals:
   def printAnimalsNames:
      print("Poo")
      def printAnimalsOwner:
        print("Poo : Jasmin")
```

how to call printAnimalsOwner from printAnimalsNames ?

Comment: You just call it normally after the definition. Not sure if this was intended but `def printAnimalsNames` is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You can call just like any other method as:

```
class Animals:
    def printAnimalsNames(self):
        print("Poo")
        x = 10

        def printAnimalsOwner():
            print("Poo : Jasmin")
            print(x)
    
        printAnimalsOwner()
        
animal = Animals()
animal.printAnimalsNames()
```

However, a note that you can't call it from outside of `printAnimalsNames` since it is local to that method only.

Comment: no. i want to call it from printAnimalsNames not outside of printAnimalsNames